# make div fill all remaining/available width

Tags: html, css, width

CSS

```
#floatright_a {
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
    float: right;
}
#floatright_b {
    background-color: #ffc0ff;
    float: right;
}
#floatright_c {
    background-color: #c0ffc0;
    /*float: right;*/
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="floatright_a">A</div>
<div id="floatright_b">B</div>
<div id="floatright_c">C</div>
```

fiddle

```
https://jsfiddle.net/0ty3o56u/
```

Given the example above, how C could take all the remaining available space to the left?

Comment: It's nice to provide fiddle but you should also post the full code here !

Comment: Ho sorry! only avoiding the last float works, sorry again

Comment: Sadly its not possible to create a div with the width of the remaining space. Floats don't work like that. There are alternative solutions to get most effects though. The content in a non floated element will flow around the float. This may give you the effect you need. It's hard to say without seeing your design.

Comment: (edit bad link) you can go for a table display like this https://jsfiddle.net/0ty3o56u/2/ - I don't like those at all since it dates back to stone age,  and I don't always understand how it really works, but I found that sometimes it's the best option

Comment: Are the widths of A and B fixed?

Answer (score -1):

```css
#floatright_a {
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    z-index:1;
    right:10px;
}
#floatright_b {
    background-color: #ffc0ff;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    z-index:1;
}
#floatright_c {
    background-color: #c0ffc0;
    float: right;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    z-index:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="floatright_c">C</div>
<div id="floatright_a">A</div>
<div id="floatright_b">B</div>
```

By positioning, you can position elements on top of eachother, this way, you could have the element C fill the whole screen, and have the elements `a` and `b` position on top of it. Sadly enough i dont have a way of giving the div a fluid width, might come back for this later.

Comment: The same effect can be achieved by omitting the float for c.